# How to deduplicate data fetches in children routes

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

Imagine the following routes. I'm using Vue and vue-router syntax right now, but I figure the question applies to other SPA frameworks as well.

```
{
    path: 'user/:id', component: require('User.vue'),
    children: [
        { path: 'edit', component: require('UserEdit.vue'), }
    ]
}
```

In User.vue, the user object is fetched using the route id parameter upon component creation:

```
data() {
    return { user: null }
},

created() {
    this.user = fetchUser(this.$route.params.id)
}
```

In UserEdit.vue, a user is also fetched, and in 85% of the cases this will be the user that was also fetched in User.vue:

```
data() {
    return { user: null }
},

created() {
    this.user = fetchUser(this.$route.params.id)
}
```

**Question**: if we would navigate from User.vue to UserEdit.vue, it is apparent that (most probably) the same user object will be fetched again. How can this kind of code duplication be avoided? How should I pass the previously fetched data down to a child route?

I guess I should somewhere check if the route parameters remain equal, because if they aren't we're editing another user and the User data should be fetched anyway...

Time for a state management store (like vuex)? If so, when the app navigates away from user pages, should the user store be cleared, or do you keep the last fetched user always in memory?

I'm having a hard time to come up with something DRY.

Looking forward to your advice and some hands-on code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use vuex for state management.  For example, setting something like `lastUser` and `userData` which could be accessed from any component.  `fetchUser` would then be an action in the store:

**Store**

```
state: {
  lastUser: '',
  userData: null
},
actions: {
  fetchUser({ state }, user) {
    if (state.userData && user == state.lastUser) {
      return state.userData;
    } else {
      // Api call, set userData and lastUser, return userData
    }
  }
}
```

**User**

```
async created() {
  this.user = await this.$store.dispatch('fetchUser', this.$route.params.id);
}
```

**UserEdit**

```
async created() {
  this.user = await this.$store.dispatch('fetchUser', this.$route.params.id);
}
```

Comment: Would you advice keeping all fetched users in userData, keeping only an id in lastUser and then return the user object by searching userData using the lastUser id? Or just keep one user object in userData. If so, what's the main benefit of introducing lastUser then?

Comment: @Propaganistas - Either way is ok, so whichever is more useful for your app.  If it was sensitive login data, maybe you wouldn't want that to be available to the next user, so you would clear it.  In that case, `lastUser` is what prevents you from fetching the same user again.  But if it's some kind of user management functionality, it would probably make more sense to fetch all user info at once and simply grab the correct user in `created`.